# Nginx location matching issues

Tags: nginx

Nginx is proxying for a Node server, serving regular http requests and websockets.

GET requests to `/download/<some directory>` are falling through to the last `/` location block.

The NGINX config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


  location ^~ /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/example/.well-known/;
    allow all;
  }

  root /var/www/example/;

  location /api {
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  location /upload {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/upload;
  }

  location /download {
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

How to properly match requests with the following format?

`/download/<some directory>`

Comment: I just tried your template and for me, the location match also works for /download/<some directory>

Comment: @QiongWu I'm sure I've done this a thousand times.  I was hoping I'd just made a silly mistake somewhere and a few more eyes might find it.  This is starting to get to me.

Comment: Do a `curl -v http://<host>/download/<directory>`, add the output to your question. If you get a 301, then you know what might be wrong

Comment: Solved.  Typo when `scp` to server. :|